# ubuntu 14.10 and ros installation error help me

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have ubuntu 14.10 and i am taking error while making installation ros. Please someone can say me this error. what is reason. What can i do

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200276/ubuntu-14.10-and-ros-installation-error-help-me/) by [ayana](https://answers.ros.org/users/21064/ayana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayana](https://answers.ros.org/users/21064/ayana/) on 2014-12-31**:
Is version of Ubuntu problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric does not officially support -i.e. there is no pre-built for- Ubuntu 14.10 as can be seen in [REP 3 - Target Platforms](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#electric-emys-aug-2011) since it is released in 2011. You can install ROS Electric on Ubuntu 10.04/10.10/11.04/11.10.

Also please read [FAQ](http://answers.ros.org/faq/).

---

Originally posted by [emreay](https://answers.ros.org/users/12731/emreay/) with karma: 90 on 2014-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0